# How can i detect whether a page redirects with javascript without running javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I want to check for dead links. There are some websites which redirect using javascript. How can I find the webpages? I crawl them with a python script that does not run javascript for performance reasons.

One idea is to look for things in the body of the html page like these described in [enter link description here](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html). I don't want to make it complicated. I am currently thinking of running a regular expression that tries to identify these instances. Any other idea?

Comment: And you are going to run a regular expression against every linked JavaScript file on the page too? It is not as simple as looking for a sting in the source. Especially if the JS is minimized.

Comment: For such cases there is only one effective solution - a headless browser, such as PhantomJS (meaning you actually need to run JS).

Comment: I see your point. Nevertheless, I don't see a solution other than executing the javascript on each site.